# What is the correct way to install laravel in laradock?

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, laradock

I have install and setup laradock in my machine and did the following as per the documentation.

1. sudo docker-compose up -d mysql nginx php-fpm workspace phpmyadmin
2. sudo docker-compose exec workspace bash
3. composer create-project laravel/laravel blog

with the above commands the laravel is installed successfully but I get the following error:

> The stream or file "/var/www/blog/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not
> be opened in append mode: failed to open stream: Permission denied

And found out in doc that I need to pass user to bash to avoid this error. So I did:

1. sudo docker-compose up -d mysql nginx php-fpm workspace phpmyadmin
2. docker-compose exec --user=laradock workspace bash
3. composer create-project laravel/laravel blog

With the above commands I get error:

> Creating a "laravel/laravel" project at "./blog" Installing
> laravel/laravel (v7.12.0) [ErrorException] mkdir(): Permission denied

Can anyone help me to setup laravel in laradock.

Comment: https://laradock.io/getting-started/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a bit of digging I found out that I need to run the following commands:

*`docker-compose exec workspace bash`

*`chmod -R 777 project-folder/storage`

Comment: never give 777 to folders. 775 would be good. Try to follow this during development as well.